# Как лучше сделать ввод данных?

Tags: java

Всем привет, я окончательно запутался в вводе данных, в видеоуроках говорили писать `a= cin.nextInt();` Позже на мой предыдущий вопрос ответили. Ниже я цитирую человека:

> Считывайте строку целиком (nextLine()) и преобразуйте в к нужному типу (Integer.parseInt):

Вопрос: почему лучше делать именно так? Спасибо!
Код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);

        // вариант 1
        String a;
        a = cin.nextLine();
        int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
        System.out.println(b);

        // вариант 2
        Int a;
        a = cin.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно целое число - cin.nextInt(), про преобразование строки бред. Если введут не число - исключение все-равно вылетит. Только не в сканнере, а при преобразовании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит использовать nextLine потому, что одним и тем же сканером, обычно, считывают разные данные. Предположим вы заносите в программу int id и String name. Id вы считываете с помощью nextInt(), а name с помощью nextLine().`int id = scanner.nextIn(); String name = scanner.nextLine();` и этот код работать не будет. Потому, что nextInt оставляет после себя символ новой строки, который считает nextLine(). Чтобы этого не произошло между чтением id и name нужно вызвать еще еще один раз scanner.nextLine() - он считает символ новой строки и дальше уже можно вводить name. Чтобы не путаться во всем этом - проще все считывать nextLine(), а потом приводить к нужным типам.